# « Mais que tu [...], que tu [...], que tu [...], tu vois ça ne s'achète pas [...] » : comment fonctionne la conjonction « mais » dans cette phrase ?

Tags: sens, conjonctions, syntaxe, paroles-de-chanson, phrase

Dans une chanson on peut entendre les paroles suivantes :

> **Mais** que tu n'aies rien, que tu sois roi,
>  Que tu cherches encore les pouvoirs qui dorment en toi
> **tu vois** ça ne s'achète pas
>  Quand tu l'as, tu l'as,
>
> [ France Gall, [*Ella, elle l'a*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ella,_elle_l%27a) (Berger, 1987), à [2:23](https://youtu.be/lgHGU8gqz9U?t=142), je souligne ]

Je crois que je m'attendais à trouver « bien que » après « tu vois » ce qui veut dire que je semble faire un lien (« mais tu vois (bien que) ça... ») mais je reste un peu perplexe comme il semble me manquer de mots...

---

Comment fonctionne cette conjonction et la phrase : quelle est la fonction de la conjonction *mais* et de quel emploi s'agit-il ; y a-t-il un lien entre la conjonction et le verbe *voir* ; est-ce que ça signifie autre chose que « mais, peu importe [la condition, la réflexion], ça ne s'achète pas... » ; doit-on ponctuer autrement ?

Answer (score 2):

Voici comment j'analyse ce couplet:

> Mais quand tu as cette petite flamme en toi, [que tu n'aies rien, que tu sois roi ou que tu cherches encore], cette flamme tu l'as. Tu vois, cette flamme ne s'achète pas.

Comment: Si tu l'as, tu l'as, et si tu ne l'as pas, tu ne l'auras jamais.

Comment: @PeterShor Oui, elle est innée. Tu ne pourras pas te la procurer avec de l'argent.

Comment: Et les pouvoirs qui dorment en toi ne te la donneront pas.

Comment: Je suis d'accord. Comme le suggère l'OP, on pourrait mettre une virgule après _je vois_, et faire deux phrases.

Answer (score -1):

Il est nécessaire de considérer ce qui précède, c'est la clé à la compréhension.

> C'est comme une gaieté
> Comme un sourire
> Quelque chose dans la voix
> […]
> Elle a ce tout petit supplément d'âme
> Cet indéfinissable charme
> Cette petite flamme
>
> Tape sur des tonneaux
> Sur des pianos
> Sur tout ce que dieu peut te mettre entre les mains
> Montre ton rire ou ton chagrin
>
> Mais que tu n'aies rien, que tu sois roi
> Que tu cherches encore les pouvoirs qui dorment en toi
> Tu vois ça ne s'achète pas

Cette occurrence de « mais » se comprends selon la définition suivante de l'usage de ce mot dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mais).

> **II**. − [Mais s'emploie en tête d'un énoncé en réaction à une situation dont le locuteur refuse telle ou telle conséquence ou telle ou telle conclusion qu'on pourrait en tirer]
> **A**. − [Coordonnant des énoncés]
> **1**. [Sert à contester le contenu de ce qui est dit]
> **a)** [La contestation porte sur la conclusion elle-même]
> **α)** [L'énoncé du locuteur se présente comme appuyant une conclusion opposée à celle qu'on peut tirer de l'énoncé de l'interlocuteur (réel ou fictif)]
> **[** Il [(user LPH) le locuteur] récuse une présupposition contenue dans l'énoncé de l'interlocuteur [(user LPH) encore le locuteur] **]**

**0/** L'antécédent de « ça » est assemblé à partir de termes explicites dans « C'est comme une gaité … petite flamme » (i) (antécédent : gaité, sourire, voix, quelque chose qui danse, qui met dans un drôle d'état, etc.)
**1/** (II) « Mais » est en tête de l'énoncé « que tu n'aies rien, … achètes pas » c'est en réaction à une situation dont le locuteur refuse une conclusion qu'on peut en tirer.
**2/** (A)  Les énoncés coordonnés sont « Tape sur des … ton chagrin » (ii) et  « que tu n'aies rien, … ça ne s'achète pas » (iii).
**3/** (1.) « Mais » sert à contester le contenu de ce qui est dit dans « ii ».
**4/** (a)) La contestation porte sur la conclusion de ce qui est dit dans « ii ».
**5/**  (α)) L'énoncé du locuteur se présente comme appuyant une conclusion opposée à celle qu'on peut tirer de l'énoncé de l'interlocuteur [(user LPH) lequel interlocuteur est fictif, puisque c'est le locuteur elle-même qui énonce « ii » ]
**6/** ([ ]) Il [(user LPH) le locuteur] récuse une présupposition contenue dans l'énoncé de l'interlocuteur [(user LPH) encore le locuteur], lequel affirme « ii », c'est à dire « tu peux faire tout ce que tu veux  (« taper sur des tonneaux, etc. », ce qui veut dire faire « comme » (ils battent des tambours) les personnes en question qui ont « ça » (dans « iii », (« ça ne s'achète pas »), ce pronom ayant pour antécédent un assemblage de termes explicites trouvés dans « i » (rappel)), et  (supposition de l'interlocuteur fictif, en l'occurrence, le locuteur) tu peux faire cela dans le but et/ou l'espoir que « ça » se dévoile en toi, c'est à dire  dans le but de faire apparaitre les qualités correspondantes (à « ça »), alors, qui que tu sois, tu n'auras pas ces dons parce qu'on ne les acquiert pas par du travail, de l'exercice ou de l'argent, on ne les achète pas.

**Note 1** « tu vois » ne sert qu'à souligner l'évidence de ce qui suit. ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voir) : 1. [Pour souligner une évidence])

**Note 2** Il n'y a pas de logique parfaite dans la récusation puisque d'une supposition que les qualités peuvent être acquise par l'exercice la chanson passe à une réfutation par l'affirmation qu'il n'y a pas « d'achat possible », alors que l'on est en droit de s'attendre à « il n'y a pas de procédé évolutif qui puisse permettre de les acquérir » (pour généraliser en termes plutôt techniques un équivalent en terms plus littéraires qui aurait pu être utilisé plus justement à la place de « ça ne s'achète pas »).

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis  Il n'y a pas de double numérotation ; les parties  de type « **1/**» sont des reprises de la définition qui sont aussi identifiées par le numéro correspondant de la définition de sorte à faire rapidement la corroboration (c'est juste au-dessus, je ne vois aucun problème). Ensuite, en ce qui concerne  la numérotation en romain, il faut s'imbiber du raisonnement, ce qui résulte en la mémorisation de ce à quoi les numéros  correspondent finalement, et de ce fait on n'a plus à chercher dans le texte ce qu'elles identifient.

Comment: On dit la même chose, mais différemment. Les _reprises_ rendent la lecture ardue à mon avis. Mais il n'est pas garanti que la présentation à laquelle je pense donne un meilleur résultat. Ça reste un commentaire sur la forme.

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Il n'y a pas d'autre moyen de vérifier que le processus que l'on croit lire dans le texte analysé suit précisément le modèle de la définition ; il faut, pour chaque point avancé, constater qu'il suit le modèle, et il faut aussi que le développement de tous les points soit d'un seul tenant pour pouvoir l'apprécier en lui-même plus facilement. On ne peut pas tout avoir, à moins de reproduire une variante de l'explication.